# Close modal which has been created in another event function

Tags: javascript, meteor, bootbox

On my first event I will open a mbox dialog. mbox is a kind of extention for bootbox, which is for showing a modal. I need mbox to use another template as modal content.

So in the modal will be loaded with the content of createElement-Template. If the user has done some input changes the modal should be closed. Therefore there is the function `modal("hide")`. 
But as `bbox` is been set in the first template-event and the closing of the modal will be done in the second template-event, I got problems to close the modal.

**events**

```
Template.main.events({
    'submit form': function(event, template) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var bbox = mbox.dialog({
            title: 'title',
            message: Template.createElement
        });
    }
});

Template.createElement.events({
    'change input': function(event, template) {
        bbox.modal('hide');
    }
});
```

**UPDATE**

The above problem works with a global var. Thanks for to Adam for that.

But not I would like to destroy a modal in a meteor package, which was created by another **package**. I tried to use a global var and I tried to use `api.export()`. But still it doesn't work. I also tried to work with Sessions.

**package-graph/lib/client/graph.js**

```
var bbox;
CanvasManager = {
    onShowAddToolTip (element) {
        bbox = mbox.dialog({ // <-- Create Modal
            title: "Title",
            message: Template.search, // <-- Loading Template search with just one input field with typeahead
        });
    },
}

CanvasManger.create(...);
```

**package-graph/lib/package.js**

```
api.export('bbox');
```

The second package provide a typeahead-searchbox (`sergeyt:typeahead`). By creating the modal in the first package, the Template will be loaded in the modal (`helloludger:mbox`). Now the user can search via typeahead and select an item. After the selection the modal should be destroyed by `modal('hide').

**package-search/lib/client/events.js**

```
Template.searchMain.onRendered(function() {
    Meteor.typeahead.inject();
});
```

**package-search/lib/client/helper.js**

```
Template.search.helpers({ // <-- getting the data for the input typeahead
    searchData: function() {
        return [
            {
                name: 'cat1',
                valueKey: 'title',
                displayKey: 'title',
                header: '<h3 class="category-name">Category</h3>',
                template: 'searchResults',
                local: function() {
                    return Collection.find().fetch();
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    selected: function(event, suggestion) { // <-- by selecting an item, I can process the data and remove the modal
            // do something
            bbox.modal('hide'); // <!-- destroy modal
            return;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Could you also post the HTML? In Meteor you can share and access state objects on the template instance via Template.instance().

Comment: If you remove the var in front of bbox you should be able to access it across files. Try changing var bbox; to bbox = null;

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make `bbox` a global variable:

```
var bbox;
Template.main.events({
    'submit form': function(event, template) {
        event.preventDefault();

        bbox = mbox.dialog({
            title: 'title',
            message: Template.createElement
        });
    }
});

Template.createElement.events({
    'change input': function(event, template) {
        bbox && bbox.modal('hide');
    }
});
```

Comment: @user3142695 - you have no guarantees that `bbox` has been set at this point (it may still be `undefined`). `bbox && doSomething()` is the same as saying `if(bbox) { doSomething() }`, just a JavaScript shorthand

Comment: I tried to use the global var, which works for the first example. But I have problems with the same thing in case of working with packages. I updated the post to make that more clear. Please have a look at it.

Answer (score 2):

Don't do this - [it violates software engineering principles.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(computer_programming))

The reason you have struggled to find a solution is a strong hint that this is not a good way to structure your app.

- You want packageMBox to embed packageTypeAhead, implying that packageMBox depends on packageTypeAhead.
- And you want packageTypeAhead to reach into packageMBox and control it, requiring (thanks Gaelan) that packageTypeAhead depend on packageMBox.

This is *bidirectional coupling*, and even if you find a way to make it work, what did you achieve?  You have two packages, neither of which can be used (or even tested properly) independently.

So the solution is:  **Combine the two packages into one package**.

'[Package for everything](http://howwedoapps.com/2015/07/16/how-i-develop-meteorjs-apps-part1)' is a good way to structure your app, but it is important to consider how and where you split functionality so you do not create more problems than you started with.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the second package has a dependency on the first:

```
api.use('first-package')
```

Only exports from dependencies are available.

[Relevant](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/namespacing) [Meteor](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/pack_export) [docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/pack_use)

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to hack around with global variables, you can also hack around with your `mbox`.

```
mbox.myModal = mbox.dialog({
  title: 'title',
  message: Template.createElement
});
```

and then in **package-search/lib/client/helper.js**

```
Template.search.helpers({
    ...
    selected: function(event, suggestion) {
            mbox.myModal && mbox.myModal.modal('hide');
            mbox.myModal = null;
            return;
        }
    }
});
```

Ideally though, you would create your own third independent module to communicate between your two packages, and inject that into both packages. That way they are not coupled and can both share state.

In this shared module, you only really need a setter and getter function that holds your modal instance. I'm not familiar with meteor so I'm not sure how you are going to do that, but judging by what you've already written, it should be possible.

Add a comment if you want to work through it.

Comment: I would like to do it this way. Could you give me some code example?